# Where does the Shoggoth come from in story 1B?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

Am I missing something in the rules?  One of the objectives references a Shoggoth, but there is no mention of one on any clue, mythos, or Keeper action card.

I've read references to taking samples being involved in producing a Shoggoth, but can't find a reference to this anywhere in the rules or guides.
Help! Have I gone mad!?

Answer (score 5):

The Objective card for 1B reads (at the top, emphasis mine):

> If there are 2 sample tokens on an altar **reveal this objective and place a shoggoth** in the Ceremony Room.

Once the keeper gets 2 samples using the **Take a Sample** Keeper action and gets them back to the altar, the fun begins. :)